# Http connection unauthorized in gerrit trigger

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

I am trying to setup Rest API for gerrit trigger jenkins plugin.
I have created a service user in git.

But now when i am entering the http username/password for service user and pressing test connection . I am getting Http connection unauthorized connection.

HTTP password is nothing but the SSH public key added in the gerrit config UI.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: How did you create this user? Did you use "gerrit create-account" command? Have you set the HTTP password? I think it's a good idea to set a password...

Comment: I created through gerrit web ui...i did not explicitly set the http password...it took the ssh public key as the password...i am not getting any option to change it...

Comment: How did you create an account using Gerrit UI? SSH key is not a substitute for the password... SSH key is used for SSH access and the password on the other hand is used for HTTP connection (REST).

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar problem and then I found the solution here:
https://dev.vaadin.com/review/Documentation/dev-rest-api.html#_authentication

The gerrituser and httppassword should be used from http://gerrit-url/#/settings/http-password link. You can test that with .netrc file as well.

I don't know how your gerrit was configured so I suggest you should also try to switch from basic_auth to digest_auth. eg:

```
curl -X GET --digest -u gerrituser:httppassword http://gerrit-url/a/path/to/api

curl -X POST --digest -u gerrituser:httppassword -d '{json data}' http://gerrit-url/a/path/to/api
```

Comment: Some explanation would be really helpful. Not only throwing some code in as answer!

Comment: @g0hl1n : Sorry I assumed the extra --digest would be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

1. By sure that you have user on Gerrit
2. Generate HTTP password for this user in Gerrit settings
3. Copy repository using http (command below)

   git clone http://gerrituser:httppassword@gerrit_url/p/nameofproject.git
4. If you want use JSON file try this example command,create file body.json:

   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @body.json http://gerrituser:httppassword@gerrit_url/a/changes/Change_Id/revisions/commit/review
5. JSON files and rest command of Gerrit REST API you can find here:
   https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html

ps. the letters /a/ and /p/ are necessary, remember of user permission and HTTP password should be without slash.